# How do I fit the coefficients of a system of ODEs to a set of empirical data using MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have a system of ODEs that contains 3 unknown parameters that have to be optimised in order to fit the system to a given data set.

This is the system of ODEs that I have:

$\frac{dP}{dt} = -\alpha PS - \gamma P$

$\frac{dS}{dt} = \alpha PS - \beta S - \gamma S$

$\frac{dQ}{dt} = \beta S - \gamma Q$

($t$ = time and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants)

How can I come up with the values for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that it'll allow the model to fit perfectly with the data that is given? Could anyone guide me through on the approach? It'll be good if there's a sample code that I can make reference to as I'm not very good with matlab. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works.

$\frac{d(P+S +Q)}{dt} = -\gamma(P+S + Q)$
this equation has solution with an exponential growth(you can solve it), it is quite easy to fit the curve and get $\gamma$.

Then

$\frac{1}{S}(\frac{dQ}{dt} + \gamma Q) = \beta$. Then get $\alpha$ in similar way.

Comment: What functions do I have to use to do the fitting in order to get the value for $\gamma$?

Comment: say $y = (P+S+Q)$, then $y = y_0 e^{-\gamma t}$, thus $\log y = \log y_0 - \gamma t$, it is a linear relation now, you can use least square to fit that. see http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html and use 'poly1' to fit.